# directshow RedenStream Fails for Capture

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture, mp4

I am making an Directshow Application to Capture MP4 video. I use below graph to do so.

```
Input Stream --> MJPEG Decompressor --> x264vfw H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec --> GDCL Mpeg-4 Multiplexor --> File Writer
```

in my directshow application , i created the required filters and connect them on graph , at end i do file writer operation and redder stream using pin as capture. that part of my code is as below.

```
GUID guid;
guid = MEDIASUBTYPE_x264;

hr = gcap.pBuilder->SetOutputFileName(&guid, gcap.wszCaptureFile,
                                      &g_mp4mux, &gcap.pSink);



hr = gcap.pBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,
                                     &MEDIATYPE_Interleaved,
                                     gcap.pVCap, pVcompFilter, NULL);
if(hr != NOERROR)
{
    hr = gcap.pBuilder->RenderStream(&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,
                                        &MEDIATYPE_Video,
                                        gcap.pVCap, pVcompFilter, NULL);
    if(hr != NOERROR)
    {
        ErrMsg(TEXT("Cannot render video capture stream"));
        TearDownGraph();
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

On above code

`g_mp4mux` is  `GDCL MPEG-4 Muliplexrer`  filer

`PVcompFilter` is `x264vfw H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec` Filter

when i run above code i get HR = `E_INVALIDARG` .

no idea what is wrong in above code. 
Plz help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RenderStream` does a number of steps internally and should any error happen during the sequence, the error is forwarded back without details. Hence, `E_INVALIADRG` is all you have, you don't know if this is a wrong argument on your call or some internal.

For starters, check your arguments (you might be passing `NULL`s in 3rd and 4th parameters), then if it is not helpful replace RenderStream with direct graph building calls such as IGraphBuilder::Connect to possibly learn more about the error.

Also mention your cross-posting: [at msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/thread/48e6290b-9dfc-4095-9f66-fc01de2d0d22#dcafe27e-d6d2-4e76-82ae-92068c9e9e39)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... i try this way and back to you.

Comment: when i replaced render stream with direct graph building calls , it worked properly. i am glad it worked ,but its strange , didnt get the reason why previous was not working!!