# Directshow cant start capture twice

Tags: c++, webcam, directshow

I am trying to follow through the DirectShow examples on the windows dev center to make my own application that can capture screen and audio to video: [Capturing Video to an AVI File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318627(v=vs.85).aspx)

The first time capture starts all is ok, but at the second nothing happens, the file with video not appearing. Is it possible that I forgot to uninitialize sometfing?

UPDATE
The problem seems not to be in missing releasing. The second time stream writes the file 1.avi is creating but it empty and when the `pMediaControl->Stop();` is done it automatically deletes

UPDATE2
At the second time I found that:

```
                hr = pBuild->RenderStream(
                &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
                &MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
                pCap,                  // Capture filter.
                NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
                pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.
```

returns `E_INVALIDARG`. So I added ([using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600563/directshow-redenstream-fails-for-capture)):

```
                if (a == 1) {
                    CComPtr<IPin> sourcePin;
                    CComPtr<IPin> dumpPin;
                    sourcePin = GetPin(pMux, PINDIR_OUTPUT);
                    dumpPin   = GetPin(pCap, PINDIR_INPUT);
                    hr = ppGraph->Connect(sourcePin, dumpPin);
                }
```

And I found thaht on the second time the `dumpPin` value is NULL .The `hr = ppGraph->AddFilter(pCap, L"Capture Filter");` runs ok. Where can I dig next to find error?

(code is updated)

My code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <windows.h>
#include <dshow.h>

#include <atlbase.h>
#include <dshow.h>


#include <vector>
#include <string> 

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids")


IPin *GetPin(IBaseFilter *pFilter, PIN_DIRECTION PinDir)
{
    BOOL       bFound = FALSE;
    IEnumPins  *pEnum;
    IPin       *pPin;

    pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnum);
    while (pEnum->Next(1, &pPin, 0) == S_OK)
    {
        PIN_DIRECTION PinDirThis;
        pPin->QueryDirection(&PinDirThis);
        if (bFound = (PinDir == PinDirThis))
            break;
        pPin->Release();
    }
    pEnum->Release();
    return (bFound ? pPin : 0);
}

HRESULT EnumerateDevices(REFGUID category, IEnumMoniker **ppEnum)
{
    // Create the System Device Enumerator.
    ICreateDevEnum *pDevEnum;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SystemDeviceEnum, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDevEnum));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create an enumerator for the category.
        hr = pDevEnum->CreateClassEnumerator(category, ppEnum, 0);
        if (hr == S_FALSE)
        {
            hr = VFW_E_NOT_FOUND;  // The category is empty. Treat as an error.
        }
        pDevEnum->Release();
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT InitCaptureGraphBuilder(
    IGraphBuilder **ppGraph,  // Receives the pointer.
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 **ppBuild  // Receives the pointer.
)
{
    if (!ppGraph || !ppBuild)
    {
        return E_POINTER;
    }
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pBuild = NULL;

    // Create the Capture Graph Builder.
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&pBuild);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Create the Filter Graph Manager.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&pGraph);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Initialize the Capture Graph Builder.
            pBuild->SetFiltergraph(pGraph);

            // Return both interface pointers to the caller.
            *ppBuild = pBuild;
            *ppGraph = pGraph; // The caller must release both interfaces.
            return S_OK;
        }
        else
        {
            pBuild->Release();
        }
    }
    return hr; // Failed
}

struct Capture {
    IPropertyBag *pPropBag;
    IGraphBuilder *ppGraph;
    IBaseFilter *pCap;
    ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pBuild;
};

void DisplayDeviceInformation(IEnumMoniker *pEnum,int a)
{
    IMoniker *pMoniker = NULL;
    std::vector<Capture> captures;

    while (pEnum->Next(1, &pMoniker, NULL) == S_OK)
    {
        IPropertyBag *pPropBag;
        HRESULT hr = pMoniker->BindToStorage(0, 0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPropBag));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            pMoniker->Release();
            continue;
        }

        VARIANT var;
        VariantInit(&var);

        hr = pPropBag->Read(L"DevicePath", &var, 0);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // The device path is not intended for display.
            printf("Device path: %S\n", var.bstrVal);
            VariantClear(&var);
        }

        IGraphBuilder *ppGraph;
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 *pBuild; // Capture Graph Builder
        hr = InitCaptureGraphBuilder(&ppGraph, &pBuild);


        IBaseFilter *pCap; // Video capture filter.
        hr = pMoniker->BindToObject(0, 0, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pCap);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            std::wstring name = std::wstring(L"C:\\a\\") + std::to_wstring(a) + std::wstring(L".avi");
            const wchar_t *cname = name.c_str();
            hr = ppGraph->AddFilter(pCap, L"Capture Filter");
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                IBaseFilter *pMux;
                hr = pBuild->SetOutputFileName(
                    &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
                    cname, // File name.
                    &pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
                    NULL);              // (Optional) Receives a pointer to the file sink.

                if (a == 1) {
                    CComPtr<IPin> sourcePin;
                    CComPtr<IPin> dumpPin;

                    sourcePin = GetPin(pMux, PINDIR_OUTPUT);
                    dumpPin   = GetPin(pCap, PINDIR_INPUT);

                    hr = ppGraph->Connect(sourcePin, dumpPin);

                }

                hr = pBuild->RenderStream(
                    &PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
                    &MEDIATYPE_Video,      // Media type.
                    pCap,                  // Capture filter.
                    NULL,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
                    pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.

                                           // Release the mux filter.
                pMux->Release();

                IConfigAviMux *pConfigMux = NULL;
                hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigAviMux, (void**)&pConfigMux);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    pConfigMux->SetMasterStream(0);
                    pConfigMux->Release();
                }

                IConfigInterleaving *pInterleave = NULL;
                hr = pMux->QueryInterface(IID_IConfigInterleaving, (void**)&pInterleave);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    pInterleave->put_Mode(INTERLEAVE_CAPTURE);
                    pInterleave->Release();
                }
                pMux->Release();
            }
        }

        Capture capt;
        capt.ppGraph  = ppGraph;
        capt.pPropBag = pPropBag;
        capt.pCap = pCap;
        capt.pBuild = pBuild;
        captures.push_back(capt);

    }

    for (auto cap : captures)
    {
        IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
        cap.ppGraph->QueryInterface(&pMediaControl);
        pMediaControl->Run();
    }

    Sleep(5000);

    for (auto cap : captures)
    {
        IMediaControl* pMediaControl;
        cap.ppGraph->QueryInterface(&pMediaControl);
        pMediaControl->Stop();
        pMediaControl->Release();

        cap.pCap->Release();

        cap.ppGraph->Release();
        cap.pBuild->Release();

        cap.pPropBag->Release();
    }

    pMoniker->Release();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IEnumMoniker *pEnum;

            hr = EnumerateDevices(CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, &pEnum);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                DisplayDeviceInformation(pEnum,a);
                pEnum->Release();
            }

        }
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CoUninitialize();
    }


    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how too resolve this, so I just used spawn of external process.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to Release ppGraph, pBuild, pMediaControl and pCap at the end of DisplayDeviceInformation function and pMux at the end of the cycle. It will be better to use some sort of smart pointers instead.

Comment: Seems like it is not it, releasing all of those didn't help. :(

Comment: You still have missing releases. The first imediacontrol is not released for instance.

Comment: Look like it is not it too. When i tried to release it the program crashes. Anyway thank you for your help.